# How to install a specific version of gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

Hi all rather a basic question but it appears I have to do a bit of sysadmin today, and I was wondering the best way to install a very specific version of gcc.  I have a version on one box and I want the same on another bare box.  I did a gcc -v and this is what came back.  So is trying to replicate the below configuration on a bare box - is this a huge task?  I know how to do sudo apt-get, is that all that is necessary here?

```
kensey@yadda.com:~/cdev$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu3'--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-   checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu3)
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is just the stock standard Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Penguin GCC version.

Just install the gcc package on the other box with apt-get (assuming it is running 12.04), and you'll get the same version.

If the other box is not running 12.04 but is running Debian or Ubuntu, you can **try** and add the precise repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list temporarily, installing this gcc version with apt-get, then removing the repository. (Not recommended)