# Meaning of fields in the GCC version

Tags: gcc

When I type `gcc -v` on my Ubuntu I get the following line (among other lines):

```
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
```

So I understand that my GCC version is 4.7.3.

But in addition to that there are two more fields here: "Ubuntu/Linaro", and "4.7.3-1ubuntu1".

I guess that "Ubuntu/Linaro" means that this GCC produces executables that run on Ubuntu (in contrast, say, to Cygwin).

My question is:

What does "4.7.3-1ubuntu1" mean and why is it that both "4.7.3-1ubuntu1" and "gcc version 4.7.3" contain the same version number? (This also happens when I run "gcc -v" on Red Hat: the two strings contain the same version number.)

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer to my own question.

The string in brackets ("Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1") tells us the package this GCC is shipped as. Indeed, when I do `dpkg -l | grep gcc` I see "4.7.3-1ubuntu1" in the output.

This string is set with `--with-pkgversion` when configuring GCC (see explanation [in this link](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)). (You can see it in action [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056949/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-gcc).)

Answer (score 1):

The  "4.7.3-1ubuntu1" is the version in the distribution packaging system.

Ubuntu uses apt / dpkg / deb for its packaging, so that is the version you are using.