# How to read the output of gcc -v

Tags: gcc, redhat

If I run gcc -v or g++ -v I get below results.

```
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
```

How do I understand this?

What is (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) and what is (GCC)

Is it the OS on which this version of gcc is compiled or the is the Generation of the OS on which this version of GCC is compatible with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of fields in the GCC version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712034/meaning-of-fields-in-the-gcc-version)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'm not the expert. :/

But "Red Hat 4.4.7-16" refers to the version of GCC (Gnu C Compiler).  There's a default c compiler for each major release of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) and IIRC, you're on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I understand is, in the output

```
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
```

First part

```
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313
```

is the default version. Using this version, redhat has created its own version that is

```
(Red Hat 4.4.7-16).
```

Please, if anyone has better idea, share it.